# Static website hosting in Websphere server

Tags: java, reactjs, websphere, hosting, url-routing

I am new to Websphere and trying to host a static website in web sphere and looking for the redirection of URLs to index.html to make client side routing work.

I created the WEB-INF and web.xml to achieve routing but it doesnt seems working.

```
MyApp
---- WEB-INF
-------- web.xml
---- index.html
```

The web.xml is created like below

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <error-page>
          <error-code>404</error-code>
          <location>/index.html</location>
     </error-page>
</web-app>
```

Am i missed anything,  when i browse urls directly i am still getting 404, means the routing is not picking.

```
Eg: domain/example/1
```

Any idea/suggestion to handle this.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think <error-page> changes the code, it'll still come back as a 404, but will include the contents of index.html.

Comment: @BruceT. Thanks for the replay, but its not redirecting. I am not seeing any change in browser network tab or console

Comment: hmm, not sure, I can't recreate it on 20.003.  I get a 404 and the contents of index.html.  Maybe file permissions on index.html?  Maybe there's something in messages.log.

Comment: I think Bruce is saying that `<error-page>` will still return a 404 code, not a redirect. It will just be a 404 with page content from your index.html. (I don't _know_ this is the case until I try it, but it sounds reasonable.)

Comment: Why put a static site on WAS?  Put it in the HTTP server directly if it is truly static.  If you are getting a 404, did  you configure your HTTP WAS plugin to handle  the paths you are discussing?